# Infinite integrals$\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {{x^n} + 1} \right)}}dx} .$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How to calculate
$$\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {{x^n} + 1} \right)}}dx} .$$

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $n$?

Comment: We have $~I_n=\pi\cdot\dfrac{A_n}{n^2}+\dfrac{n\bmod2}n~,~$ where $A_n$ is an algebraic number.

Comment: @Lucian. Just for my curiosity, how did you arrive to this result ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: By reaching deep down into [the unfathomable abyss of my amazing mathematical intellect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica). :-)

Answer (score 2):

For **odd** values of *n*, use the fact that $~\dfrac n{(1+x)(1+x^n)}~=~\dfrac1{(1+x)^2}~+~\dfrac{P_{n-2}(x)}{1+x^n}~,~$ where

$P_{n-2}(x)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(n-k-1)(-x)^k,~$ in conjunction with the famous identity $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^n}~dx$

$=~\dfrac\pi n\cdot\csc\bigg(a~\dfrac\pi n\bigg),~$ which can be proven using the substitution $t=\dfrac1{1+x^n}~,~$ followed by

recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and then employing Euler's

[reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to simplify the result. For **even** values of *n*, a similar trick

applies, with the caveat that the new formulas are $~\dfrac2{(1+x)(1+x^n)}~=~\dfrac1{1+x}~+~\dfrac{R_{n-1}(x)}{1+x^n}~,~$

where $~R_{n-1}(x)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-x)^k,~$ and the rather **important observation** that, for **even** values

of *n*, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\bigg(\frac1{1+x}-\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n}\bigg)~dx~=~0.$

Comment: This is very interesting, for sure ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{(1+x)(1+x^n)}=\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}-\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{xdx}{1+x^n}$

$=\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}(B\Bigl(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n},\Bigr)-B\Bigl(\frac{2}{n},1-\frac{2}{n},\Bigr))=\dfrac{\pi}{n\sin(\pi/n)}-\dfrac{\pi}{n\sin(2\pi/n)}$.

Second try. We have

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{(1+x)(1+x^n)}$

$=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n}dx+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-k}}{1+x^n}$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-k}}{1+x^n}$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2n}B\Bigl(\frac{n-k+1}{n},1-\frac{n-k+1}{n}\Bigr)$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2n}\dfrac{\pi}{sin(\pi(n-k+1)/n)}$.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct ? How did you decompose the first integrand ? What happens for $n=2$ for which the result should be $\pi/4$ ?

Comment: Thank you, you're right I make a mistake in the second integrand. I will search an other way.

Comment: This is very interesting, for sure ! Thanks.